# How do I alert items from an array/for loop correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, alert

I am doing a project with converting a simple sentence to a statement that an 'adolescent' would say. I want to add the phrase 'you know' after each three words in the sentence that the user types in. When I print the converted sentence at the end, it seems as though there is an extra 'you know' for each one of my items (or words) in my array. How do I lose all of the extra 'you know''s at the end? Or how do I prevent that from happening? Here is my code:

```
var k = 3;
var phrase = "you know";
var sentence = prompt("Enter a sentence: ");
sentence = sentence.split(" ");

for (word in sentence) {
  sentence.splice(k, 0, phrase);
  k += 4;
}

sentence = sentence.join(" ");

alert(sentence);
```

Comment: You know, like, `for (word in sentence)` is totally not the right way to iterate over an array and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for of vs for in**

When you want to iterate over every item in an iterable (such as an array), you should use `for (let x of arr) ...` instead of `for (let x in arr)`. The latter is used for iterating over every key in an object, including prototypically inherited ones.

**Mutating what you iterate**

You are iterating over a thing and modifying it at the same time, which is always a good recipe for a headache. If you are going to mutate an array incrementally while traversing it, make a copy first: `var newSentence = sentence.slice()`, then modify that. In fact, you don't even really need to iterate the array because...

**Too many "you knows"**

Your logic is a little bit off. For an N-word sentence, you inject "you know" exactly N times; which only makes sense if you want one "you know" per word. If you want to insert every 4 words, you need to insert N / 4 times. What you need is to simply keep inserting while you haven't run off past the end of the sentence:

```
var k = 3;
var phrase = "you know";
var sentence = prompt("Enter a sentence: ");
sentence = sentence.split(" ");

while (k <= sentence.length) {
  sentence.splice(k, 0, phrase);
  k += 4;
}

sentence = sentence.join(" ");

alert(sentence);
```

Comment: Minor nitpick. You may want `k <= sentence.length`, unless the goal is to only insert "you know" if more words follow. (The question is what to do with the input "only three words" or "what about a multiple of three".)

Answer (score 0):

See the `for` loop below, which starts after the third word and increments by three words (plus the phrase we just inserted) with each iteration, stopping at the end of the sentence:

```js
var phrase = "you know";
var sentence = "This is a sentence with a bunch of words in it."; // test data instead of prompt

var words = sentence.split(" ");

for (var i = 3; i <= words.length; i += 4) {
  words.splice(i, 0, phrase);
}

console.log(words.join(" ")); // instead of alert
```

The issue with your code is that your loop executes `n` times, where `n` is the number of words in the sentence. You could fix your loop by `break`ing when `k` goes off the end of the sentence, but it's simpler to just construct a better `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
var sentence = prompt("Enter a sentence: ");
sentence = sentence.split(" ");
var newSentence = [];
for(var i = 0;i<sentence.length;i++){
 if(i!=0 && i%3==0 && i<(sentence.length-1)){
  newSentence.push("you know");
 }
newSentence.push(sentence[i]);
}
sentence = newSentence.join(" ");
```